# Is it possible to decode an array stored in strings with constraint satisfaction?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, data-compression

I am currently experimenting on compression algorithms, I am using proven algorithms and I am just trying to see if I can make some things more efficient, so I am very sorry if this is a stupid question. I am trying to decode an array from a string for example I have `[123, 4, 12, 7, 51]` so if I turn this into a string it would be "123412751" are there ways to decode this without bloating the array? like you can keep the length of this by doing something like `31231421217251` so you'd know how to decode this but the problem is you'd bloat the data needed so instead I would like to know if this is solvable with constraint satisfaction and how would I go about that?

What I did with constraint satisfaction is I'd get the sum of `[123, 4, 12, 7, 51]` which is 197 and the length needed which is 5 so now I'd look for combinations from "123412751" with a length of 5 and a sum of 197 however with larger arrays it gives me different values not really the exact one I needed, is this something that is possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "with constraints"?  Please [edit] your question to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry I meant "constraint satisfaction"

Comment: `experimenting on compression algorithms` algorithms solve problems. Compression algorithms turn original data into something smaller (cheaper to keep/transfer) that can be *decompressed* into something useful - the original if *lossless*. A useful algorithm allows implementation with non-prohibitive resource requirements - *combinations* reminds of *combinatorial explosion*: Not everything possible is *feasible*.

Comment: So what happens if you have a 10 digit number?

Answer (score 1):

I’d look first at Huffman coding and arithmetic coding, which will handle th commas and spaces quite efficiently. Or Lempel-Ziv which munches these separators away at practically no cost.

Or encode the integers as UTF-8, extended to 5 or 6 byte codes in case you have some huge integers.

Comment: I've tried this before it works quite well, however the problem is I use this arrays for characters as well so when you have a character that is above **>9**  length it will bloat the  data with significant margin so I would much prefer the ones without seperators and of course with rules of entrophy it is impossible to get the same compression ratio as without the seperators